# Block choice of same data pool when random.shuffle

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, shuffle, pool

I am working on a code that looks at choice game in a mutliple round game. There are four choice (A,B,C,D) options and four payoff pools (pool_1, pool_2, pool_3 and pool_4). Every round there is one choice to be selected. Each choice is asssigned to one pool (A - pool_1 etc).

I want to randomly shuffle the pools **once 5 in 6 choices have been the same** (e.g. AAABAA or BCBBBB -> e.g. change pool_1 to any other BUT pool_1). Also there should be an **automatic shuffle once every 20 rounds** to make sure that even if no choice is selected 5 in 6 times, that the pools stil change.

For now I have coded it the way that after 5 streaks (5 choices in a row) the pools change. I just do not manage to have the pools change after any 5 in 6 choices (having been identical) together with a change every 20 rounds and also sometimes the same pool gets randomly selected straight again, which I do not want.

`if (streak % 5) == 0 :
    pools = [pool_1, pool_2, pool_3, pool_4]
    random.shuffle(pools)`

```
work1 = pools[0]
work2 = pools[1]
work3 = pools[2]
work4 = pools[3]
```

Any help is appreaciated -thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Streak tracking

For determining if five of the last six choices are the same, you could use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to keep track of the last N choices. You'd want to [limit the size](http://codeyarns.com/2013/03/23/how-to-implement-a-queue-with-maximum-length-in-python/) to 6. Whenever a choice is made, append the choice to your deque.

```
from collections import deque
from collections import Counter

last_three_choices = deque('', maxlen=3)  # using 3 for brevity
last_three_choices.append('A')            # User picked A. History is now A
last_three_choices.append('B')            # User picked B. History is now AB
last_three_choices.append('C')            # User picked C. History is now ABC
last_three_choices.append('A')            # User picked A. History is now BCA
last_three_choices.append('C')            # User picked C. History is now CAC
```

After appending the choice, make a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) based on your deque to determine how many times each choice has been made. Filter that to only contain keys whose value is 5 or more (there should be at most one!) and if there are any, that's a choice that has been made five times in the last six trials.

```
two_out_of_three = deque('CAC')                           # Restoring state from above
streakyness = Counter(two_out_of_three)                   # This will be {'C':2, 'A':1}
streaked = {k:v for (k,v) in streakyness.items() if v>=2} # This will just be {'C':2}
```

Then you can use Python's treatment of empty dictionaries as False to extract the offending choice and perform a shuffle if there's been a streak:

```
if streaked:                             
  repeated_choice = next(iter(streaked)) # Retrieve the key
  do_shuffle_thing(repeated_choice)      # Invoke your shuffling procedure
```

## Antagonistic shuffling

For not-completely-random shuffling in which a particular element (the one that was streaked) is guaranteed to not have a particular final location (its original location), assuming you're really only dealing with a small number of choices, you could basically use a [bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) with a very relaxed 'order' criterion:

```
pool_to_move = pools[repeated_choice]
while pools[repeated_choice] == pool_to_move:
  random.shuffle(pools)
```

With each pass, you have a 1 in 6 chance of getting a bad shuffle that requires reshuffling, so after N iterations you only have a 6^N chance of needing to keep going. Theoretically it could go on forever, but unless your RNG is biased to hate games that [exploding dice](https://eric22222.wordpress.com/2009/03/22/a-mathematical-analysis-of-exploding-dice/), it should terminate quickly.

You may note I assumed that `pool` is a dictionary with choices as keys, rather than a list like you've got. But no worry: [shuffling dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17997683/5265467) is a doable thing.